# Get product attributes label name by its slug in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, custom-taxonomy

I have create product_attributes as: `Color` have slug `color` / `Size` has slug `size`

In Product: how to show `color` Name/Label by slug.

i try wc_get_product_terms but it's attributes value of `color / size` not `var_dup(color / size)` infomation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get product_attributes label name by its slug in using `wc_attribute_label()` like:

```
$attr_slug       = 'color';
$attr_taxonomy   = 'pa_' . $attr_slug; 

echo wc_attribute_label( $attr_taxonomy );
```

and

```
$attr_slug       = 'size';
$attr_taxonomy   = 'pa_' . $attr_slug; 

echo wc_attribute_label( $attr_taxonomy );
```